# Tag badge count in Activity not updating

Tags: bug, profile-page, tag-badges

I just took these screenshots:

[image]

[image]

It has said this for a long time now (I now have 12 HP answers, not 9).

**Why is my tag badge count not updating?**

<sub>I have tried switching to tracking my next priv., and tracking a different tag badge. Nope.</sub>

Comment: @rene The answer there says to do something that I tried - and it didn't mork.

Comment: Ok, that is unfortunate but that bug report isn't status-completed. I don't think we need another one. You can down vote the other answer or leave a comment.